# How can I find the consumer group id of a spark structrued streaming application?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

In spark streaming programming, we can explicitly assign the kafka consumer group id by setting below config:

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  ...
  "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
  ...
)

val rdd = KafkaUtils.createRDD[String, String](sparkContext, kafkaParams, offsetRanges, PreferConsistent)
```

In spark structured streaming setting your own consumer group id is forbidden.

In my program I am not going to change the consumer group id but reuse that group id to seek the latest offfset for the topic partitions that group has subscribed.

So is there any mehod I can get the consumer group id used implicitly in my spark application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumer group id is internally generated by the Apache Spark when creating the rdd :

```
  // So that consumers in executors do not mess with any existing group id
  .set(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, s"$uniqueGroupId-executor")
```

You can take a look on the `KafkaSourceProvider.scala` to see what is being generated. I don't suggest changing that but maybe downstream the flow to other static consumer group

Comment: Thanks. I will check that class to see how the embeded consumer group is generated. It is not quite necessary, currently i create another consumer to get the information about topic I concern.

Comment: If this answered your question mark it as answer helpful.

Comment: OK. I have mark this answer as useful, but with this feedback: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"